# Node mysql query takes a great amount of time (during its first execution) but only on my local machine

Tags: mysql, node.js

Im using the official mysql node module in a node module.

The connecting to the database happens instantly. When I execute a query though, t takes almost ten/twenty seconds for a response. The next time the query (identical SQL) is executed it is near instantaneous.

This only happens on my local machine (speaking to the same mysql database) but not on my production server(where the mysql database is located).

I had to edit my timeout values on my local machine to allow the queries to not timeout.

Edit: to clarify, I am not running a local db. I'm speaking to the production DB when I'm running from my local machine.

What could be happening here?

Comment: It sounds like you have a slow query and it takes more time on your system to execute it and cache the results. Hard to say more, though.

Comment: @dmfay the strange thing, is I'm speaking to the same exact database when querying from my local machine. Not running a local db.

Comment: You say "the next time the query..", is it the same query both times, or is it faster on all subsequent queries?

Comment: hey, when I run a query with the same SQL query. Each first run of a SQL query causes the weird behavior.

Comment: Sounds like your network connection between your local box and the server is slow or low bandwidth.  The second results for the same query being faster sounds like the driver is doing some optimization by caching it locally for some period of time.